# My program is crahing, and honestly i am confused (c++)

Tags: c++, crash

For some reason my program crashes immediately after it receives the input from the user. However the weirdest part is that it crashes only if the user was to input `Yes`, not if they input `n`o. My thoughts are that it is something to do with the class `Players`. I already have tried debugging through all conventional methods. Breakpoints do not appear to work due to the fact that if I put it after the `cout << "Is this the first time...`  none of the variables will have any data due to the fact that they have not been assigned. It worked flawlessly up until I made the `readPlayerData` function, then the crashing began.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    mt19937 rand_engine(time(nullptr));
    vector<Player> plyrs;
    srand(time(NULL));
    bool firstTimer = false;
    cout << "Is this the first time this program has run?" << endl;
    string firstTime;
    cin >> firstTime;

    if (firstTime == "Yes" || firstTime == "yes") {
        firstTimer == true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            int limit = 18; // rand() % (25 - 18) + 18;
            for (int w = 0; w < limit; w++) {
                int z = plyrs.size();
                plyrs.resize(z + 1);
                plyrs[z].setPlayeName(rand_engine);
                plyrs[z].setPlyrVal();
                plyrs[z].setPlayerTeam(i);
            }
        }
        string human_input;
        cout << "Pick a # between 1-30, this will be your team: " << endl;
        cin >> human_input;
        int human_teamInput = 0;
        human_teamInput = atoi(human_input.c_str());
        ofstream plyrdata;
        plyrdata.open("plyr.txt");
        plyrdata << human_teamInput << endl;
        plyrdata.close();
        ofstream playerSaveData;

        playerSaveData.open("savedata.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < plyrs.size(); i++) {
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].plName << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].plOvr << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].ploaw << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].pldaw << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].pldspg << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].pldsps << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].plSpg << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].plSps << endl;
            playerSaveData << plyrs[i].plteam
                           << (i < (plyrs.size() - 1) ? "\n" : "");
        }
        playerSaveData.close();
        assemble_Team_Data();
    }

    else {
        assemble_Team_Data();
    }
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for the readPlayerData()

```
void readPlayerData() {
    numFnames = 1;
    numLnames = 1;
    string line;
    ifstream fnameFile("PlayersFname.txt");
    if (fnameFile.is_open()) {
        while (fnameFile.eof() == false) {
            plFname.resize(numFnames);
            getline(fnameFile, line);
            numFnames += 1;
        }
        fnameFile.close();
    }
    ifstream lnameFile("PlayersLname.txt");
    if (lnameFile.is_open()) {
        while (lnameFile.eof() == false) {
            plLname.resize(numLnames);
            getline(lnameFile, line);
            numLnames += 1;
        }
        lnameFile.close();
    }
}
void setPlayeName(mt19937& rand_engine) {
    readPlayerData();
    uniform_int_distribution<int> fname_rand(0, numFnames);

    string fname = plFname[fname_rand(rand_engine)];
    uniform_int_distribution<int> lname_rand(0, numLnames);

    string lname = plLname[lname_rand(rand_engine)];
    plName = string(fname + " " + lname);
}
```

Comment: @PiotrS isnt it supposed to be like that when you have a bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not likely to be your crash, but this code is terrible:

```
if (fnameFile.is_open())
{
    while (fnameFile.eof() == false)
    {
        plFname.resize(numFnames);
        getline(fnameFile,line);
        numFnames += 1;
    }
    fnameFile.close();
}
```

It doesn't check for end of file correctly, because end of file happens *during* getline, not before.  And the `line` variable goes nowhere.  Try

```
while (getline(fnameFile,line)) plFnames.push_back(line);
fnameFile.close();
```

Comment: does that have the same effect as the .eof? so that it knows when it has reached the end of the file?

Comment: @Gorlan: `getline` returns the stream itself, and `while (stream)` checks if the stream is still in a good state.  Not being open or reaching the end of file will put the stream in a fail state and end the loop.

Comment: (It works by using the "contextual conversion to bool", triggered by the condition of a while loop.  And `fstream`'s conversion to `bool` returns whether the stream is good)

Comment: @Gorlan: Also use `plFNames.size()` when picking a name at random, instead of `numFnames`.  The vector remembers its own size.

Comment: Still crashes after switching the numFnames and numLnames

Comment: @Gorlan: Sorry, without the information from your debugger (what line crashes, what are the variables at that time), I can't see the problem.

Comment: I fixed it, have no clue how, but thanks for helping me with my code!